# Zip CSV File using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv, zip

I built a macro that writes a custom csv file to disk. I need to add the option to also save this file in a zipped format. I followed Ron de Bruins excellent [article](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm) on the matter but face the problem that my zip file is empty.

```
NewZip (FilePathZip) 'creates an empty zip file
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.Namespace(FilePathZip).CopyHere FilePathCSV
```

FilePathZip is the full path to the new zip file I'm creating here. FilePathCSV is the full path to the CSV that was just saved to disk. Interestingly, when I switch out FilePathCSV for any other file that already exists before I run the macro, it works. Apparently, I only face this problem when trying to zip a file that was created during the runtime of the macro.

I already checked if the CSV path is recognized by excel through Dir(FilePathCSV) and made sure that the file is closed after the writing process. I also tried adding timeouts (Wait()). I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: yeah I've had asynchronous issues with this, I'd persist with waiting and polling.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping `FilePathCSV` in a `Dir()` function solved my problem. I'm not sure why though.